# WSO2 Identity Server - event handler - what events are handled?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

The WSO2 Identity Server since version 5.1 has an option to engage the workflow on certain events using a custom event event/workflow handler. Nice!  What events is it possible to handle? Well - from the [example](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Writing+a+Custom+Event+Handler) I see that any admin web service calls could be intercepted.

Next to that - I found the org.wso2.carbon.identity.event bundle providing option to handle events. What events is this feature intended?

Thank you all for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We developed identity-event component with the initial intention to handle events related to identity-management such as account lock, account disable, password reset, failed login attempt etc. We developed `AbstractEventHandler`which defines different methods of handling events such as sending notifications. Account locking act as a method of handling events as well at the time of incorrect login attempt. Successful login attempt after failed login attempt also act as event where handler will reset the user's failed login attempt claim. We can map events to handler in repository/conf/identity/event-mgt.properties file. So we can register each events to 0 or more handlers which will fired when the event occurs.

Even though the initial intention of this event framework was to handle identity management event, later we improved it to be a more generic framework which can handle any event which we can describe in model I mentioned above. But as far as I know this only covers identity-management related event. But anyone who develop customize features can make use of this.

Its true that workflow handler is also a way of handling events which do the same task this framework do for some extent. After reading your question, I also got feeling that it also follows the same model. But we haven't thought of combining these two. So they will work as independent features.

Comment: Can you give the link to github where account lock, account disable, password reset, failed login handler implementations are?